# Controller returning file header to view not file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

My form looks like this

```
{
 using (Ajax.BeginForm("Log",
                        new AjaxOptions { 
                            UpdateTargetId = "lessonTable"
                        }))

  //removed dropdown list ect... for readability

 input type="submit" name = "submitButton" value = "Filter"          
 input type="submit" name = "submitButton" value = "Print Report"
```

and my controller does this

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Log(lesson lesson,string submitButton)
    {
        /*Retreive all lessons*/
        List<lesson> lessonList = (from l in storeDB.lessons
                                   where l.statusID != DELETED 
                                   select l).ToList();

        /*Filter retreived Lesson*/
        lessonList = filterLesson(lesson,lessonList);

        switch (submitButton)
        {

            case "Filter":
                return PartialView(lessonList);

            default:
                {
                    return DetailsReport();
                }
        }


    }
```

the DetailsReport() method returns a File

```
 return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
```

when click the Print Report button it is updating the div with the file header not requesting that the user opens the file.   I have tried removing updatetarget ID but it doesn't prompt for a file download.  Also when I make an ajax.actionlink call to the details report method it is working fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are doing, it is working as intended; because you are making the request from an `Ajax.BeginForm()`, it is trying to display what ever is returned in the page. Removing the target would not be expected to change that.

You should simply make the "Print Report" button be part of a separate form or not a form at all, and have it pull the info it needs from the existing form before submitting (since it wouldn't do it automatically once it is removed from that form)